# replace characters and retain the numbers and dot in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this number format (2,100.00 units), how to remove the characters and retain the numbers and dot(.)? I try this one but no good 
`percentValueElement.replace(/,\(\)/g, '').replace(/[^[a-z]\.]+/g, "")`

Comment: Why this question has a down votes?

Comment: percentValueElement.replace(/,\(\)/g, '').replace(/[^[a-z]\.]+/g, "")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
percentValueElement.replace(/[^0-9.]/ig, '');
```

Or as David suggested:

```
percentValueElement.replace(/[^\d.]/ig, '');
```

Comment: You could use: [`/[^\d.]/ig`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: No problem at all! ...bearing in mind that, while it has regex-special character cool, it does only save *one* character, so...it's pretty near a pointless change, but it is still an alternative. =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep your thousandseparator?

Then you should write something like

```
var numberformat = /[(0-9)+(.|,)?]+/igm;
var number = numberformat.exec("2,100.00 units");
```

or shorter

```
  var numberformat = /[\d+(.|,)?]+/igm;
```

Comment: actually no, because I used parsefloat to convert the number. once it has a seperator I didn't get the exact value. Thanks for your answer.